# .htaccess rewrites root to subfolder, yet subfolder app 302 redirects right back to full path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mantis

I have a standard .htaccess RewriteRule that silently rewrites any request for webroot into a subfolder which contains a MantisBT installation.  So the user types in "example.com" and my server secretly serves them files from "example.com/path/to/mantisbt".

The problem now is that MantisBT's index page immediately does some authentication based logic routing and sends a 302 redirect to the FULL "example.com/path/to/mantis/login", which subverts my rewriting. I'm trying to have everyone access my MantisBT installation as if it resided in the webroot.

Now, I'm aware that after MantisBT's 302 redirect to the full path, I could redirect them AGAIN back to webroot. But redirecting people twice every time MantisBT goes through some routing logic seems like a dirty hack.  I also know that I could hack up the MantisBT code, but I hate re-hacking code every time a new version comes out.

So, is there a way to trick MantisBT (or any other app for that matter) into thinking it resides in root, and therefore crafts it's redirect paths based on a webroot-relative url? For example: "example.com/login" instead of "example.com/path/to/mantis/login".

I'd really prefer to resolve this using an Apache .htaccess method, or httpd.conf change. Perhaps DocumentRoot or RewriteBase?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this rule above the internal rewrite rule that you had before

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+path/to/mantisbt/([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
```

this redirects the browser when the browser directly requests anything in `/path/to/mantisbt/`. Then the rule that you already have to internally rewrite into the mantisbt directory would take effect.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Given the [R] flag, this would generate another redirect in addition to the one MantisBT had already sent to the full location.  As I mentioned above, I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve a second redirect.  I was hoping that I could fool MantisBT into thinking it resided in root, so that it's initial redirect was already targeted for the webroot, and the true path of MantisBT is never revealed to the browser (even in header redirects).

Comment: @uberdanzik Not sure why you're trying to "fool" MantisBT instead of just configuring it so that it returns links that a based from the root. Somewhere you have it configured to return links like `/path/to/mantisbt/`